# How to clean zombie process

Tags: android, linux, kill

do as follows:

```
root@m0032dvr:/ # ps | grep native
root      4064  3956  80160  8012  futex_wait b6d795ec S nativecamera
root@m0032dvr:/ # kill 4064
root@m0032dvr:/ # ps | grep native                                             
root      4064  3956  0      0        do_exit 00000000 Z nativecamera
```

kill again:

```
root@m0032dvr:/ # kill 4064                                                    
root@m0032dvr:/ # ps | grep native                                             
root      4064  3956  0      0        do_exit 00000000 Z nativecamera
```

kill ppid:

```
root@m0032dvr:/ # kill 3956                                                    
root@m0032dvr:/ # ps | grep native                                             
root      4064  3956  0      0        do_exit 00000000 Z nativecamera
```

so, **kill** can release the ***nativecamera***'s resource, but make it change to zombie, which can't be clean totally.

kill -9 [pid], not effect.

```
root@m0032dvr:/ # kill -9 2711                                                 
root@m0032dvr:/ # ps | grep -i native                                          
root      2711  2261  0      0        do_exit 00000000 Z nativecamera
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the [manual for kill](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html). You can send different signals, by default kill will send SIGTERM which signals the process to execute its shutdown routines and exit, but a zombie process will not be able to action that. You should send SIGKILL to a zombie with `kill -9 [pid]` so the OS does not wait for the process to exit but terminates it abruptly w/o leaving the chance to the process to do anything.

Comment: It doesn't work
`root      2711  2261  0      0        do_exit 00000000 Z nativecamera`